# Ubuntu netplan arp-ip-target issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bonding

I have ubuntu 20.04 running netplan version `0.102-0ubuntu1~20.04.2` and i am trying to configure `active-backup` bond with using option `arp-ip-target`

```
  bonds:
        bond0:
          dhcp4: no
          interfaces:
            - eno49
            - eno50
          parameters:
            mode: active-backup
            arp-ip-targets: [ 10.64.0.1 ]
            arp-interval: 3000
```

Here is my bond output

```
# cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: fault-tolerance (active-backup)
Primary Slave: None
Currently Active Slave: eno49
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 0
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0
Peer Notification Delay (ms): 0
ARP Polling Interval (ms): 3000
ARP IP target/s (n.n.n.n form): 10.64.0.1

Slave Interface: eno50
MII Status: down
Speed: 10000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 1
Permanent HW addr: 5c:b9:01:9d:ac:ad
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eno49
MII Status: up
Speed: 10000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 5c:b9:01:9d:ac:ac
Slave queue ID: 0
```

for testing i disable upstream switch port to see it my bond failover but look like it doesn't work. what else i should to to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding `arp_validate: all` it works!!

```
parameters:
  mode: active-backup
  arp-ip-targets: [ 10.64.0.1 ]
  arp-interval: 3000
  arp-validate: all
```

Comment: I'm a little confused on the arp-ip-targets. Is it supposed to be whatever switch you're connected to? Say I'm connected to `192.168.2.10` does that mean `arp-ip-targets` would be `192.168.2.10`?

Comment: arp-ip-targets can be any machine in your datacenter you want to test connectivity. I prefer my gateway ip for arp ping. It will just send arp ping to test you have connectivity if test fail then it will try other standby nic in bond to reach out. (This way you know if switch is failed or not)